# Is there any significance to the prison numbers of the Beagle Boys starting with 176-?

Tags: disney, ducktales

One of the things which has puzzled me since my childhood are the prison numbers of the [Beagle Boys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beagle_Boys):

[image: The Beagle Boys dancing and singing together with their arms around each other's backs; their numbers are all 176-NNN where NNN is a permutation of 176]
<sub>(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beagle_Boys#/media/File:The_Beagle_Boys.jpg))</sub>

They all start with 176- followed by a permutation of those digits. The Wikipedia page mentions that these numbers were first applied to the third generation of Beagle Boys and not always consistently, but all comics I have read did use the 176 numbering scheme.

Is there any significance in the number 176 or the digits 1, 6, 7? Did [Carl Barks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Barks) choose those numbers for any particular reason? Maybe there was no specific reason, but there might be an in-universe explanation for these numbers out there.

Comment: His wife at the time was Clara Barks. She was born on the 17th of *May*, 1898.

Comment: If it had only been the 17th of June ...

Comment: I was thinking that it might be referring to a provision of the California Penal Code (the way hip hop uses "187" as slang for "murder", but §176 is repealed nowadays and used to refer to "Omission of Duty by Public Officer", so that's unlikely to be the explanation.

Comment: Voted to leave open,didn't we agree some time ago that all _Ducktales_ were on-topic?

Comment: @Jenayah - Yes [we did](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11519/is-ducktales-on-topic)

Answer (score 8):

There doesn't appear to be any particular significance to the "176" itself. Carl Barks appears to have used it to differentiate them, since they were basically identical in every other way, and seldom given names. [Some later  comics used anagrams of the 176 prefix as well](https://disneycomics.fandom.com/wiki/The_Beagle_Boys_(characters))

> The three most common numbers are 176-167, 176-671, and 176-761. Carl Barks used to include the words "Beagle Boys Inc" on their shirts under their numbers, but this was later discontinued. In later years, they appeared in the comics as a trio (some combination of the most common numbers with 671-176, 716-617 and 176-176), plus cousins and other relatives of various talents.

Only [Blackheart Beagle](https://disneycomics.fandom.com/wiki/Blackheart_Beagle) has a number that doesn't fit 176 the mold (186-802).

The Ducktales TV series was the first time we saw any differentiation. In keeping with Barks' trope, all of them (except [Ma Beagle](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Ma_Beagle)) had 176 number plaques. Unlike the comics, they were also differentiated by body type

[image: Four of the Beagle Boys walking down the street together, they have the 176-NNN numbers on their chests]

Comment: Actually the Beagleboys did have names in Ducktales. The short one was called Bigtime, The untidy one was Baggy, The hungry one Burger and the big one Bouncer. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beagle_Boys